# Need help in update a CLOB field(xml type) in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a column with `CLOB` and it has a data of type `XML`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testRules version="1.0">
    <rule id="1839" name="remit_amount.minimum.dollar_amount">
        <value order="1" modifiedBy="admin" modifiedDate="04/10/2012 15:04:49">5.00</value>
    </rule>
    <rule id="1840" name="remit_amount.maximum.dollar_amount">
        <value order="1" modifiedBy="admin" modifiedDate="04/10/2012 15:04:49">1000.00</value>
    </rule>
</testRules>
```

Now I want to update `<rule id="1840">`'s `<value` to 1500.00.

Please help me to get the right update script for the above change.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below sample example and replace your table details--

```
create table t1 ( x clob );

INSERT
INTO t1 VALUES
  (
    '<Test>      
<GROUP_TYPE>PR</GROUP_TYPE>      
<GROUP_NAME a ="asdsada">A</GROUP_NAME>      
<GROUP_NAME b ="bbbb">B</GROUP_NAME>  
<UNIT>C</UNIT>               
</Test>'
  );

commit;


    UPDATE t1
SET x= updatexml(xmltype.createxml(x),'/Test/GROUP_NAME/text()','CCC').getclobval()
WHERE ExtractValue(xmltype(x),'/Test/GROUP_NAME/@a')='asdsada';

commit;
```

This will give you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [UPDATEXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions225.htm#SQLRF06172)

```
   UPDATE test_xml SET col =
   UPDATEXML(xmltype(col),
   '/testRules/rule[@id="1839"]/value/text()','1500.00').getClobval();
```

Note that the predicate in the XPATH expression limits the update to the proper element.
Note also that this statement update all rows in the table, so add WHERE condition if appropriate.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <testRules version="1.0">
   <rule id="1839" name="remit_amount.minimum.dollar_amount">
     <value order="1" modifiedBy="admin" modifiedDate="04/10/2012 15:04:49">1500.00
     </value>
   </rule>
   <rule id="1840" name="remit_amount.maximum.dollar_amount">
     <value order="1" modifiedBy="admin" modifiedDate="04/10/2012 15:04:49">1000.00
     </value>
   </rule>
 </testRules>
```